# Is there any way to pass props to textfield in react phone number input library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-phone-number-input

I am using react-phone-number-input library to take phone number inputs from users with country code. I added extra text-field as an inputComponent props of this component. My component is,

```js
<PhoneInput
   international
   defaultCountry="BD"
   placeholder="Enter phone number"
   value={phoneNumber}
   onChange={handlePhoneNumberOnChange}
   countryCallingCodeEditable={false}
   inputComponent={TextFieldPhoneInput}
/>
```

Is there any way to pass some others props to the TextFieldPhoneInput component which i used inside inputComponent? Reasons behind passing props to the TextFieldPhoneInput is, i want to validate the textfield and show some error messages as label after validation.

Comment: Try using `inputComponent={inputProps => <TextFieldPhoneInput {...inputProps} {...yourOtherProps} />}`

Comment: Getting this error after adding props.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after adding my needed props touched, errors, directly to the  component and wrapped the inputComponent with forwardRef. My Solution is,

```
<PhoneInput
  international
  defaultCountry="BD"
  placeholder="Enter phone number"
  value={phoneNumber}
  onChange={handlePhoneNumberOnChange}
  countryCallingCodeEditable={false}
  touched={touched}
  errors={errors}
  inputComponent={TextFieldPhoneInput}
  />
```

and inside TextFieldPhoneInput component,

```
const TextFieldPhoneInput = (props, ref) => {
    const {touched,errors} = props
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <TextField
            {...props}
            InputProps={{
                className: classes.input
            }}
            inputRef={ref}
            fullWidth
            // size='small'
            label='Phone Number'
            variant='outlined'
            name='phone'
            error={Boolean(touched && errors)}
            helperText={touched && errors}
        />
    );
};

TextFieldPhoneInput.propTypes = {};
export default forwardRef(TextFieldPhoneInput)
```

Now, everything works fine.

Comment: I think this is not fare that You go the idea from one solve and you posted your answer and made it correct. You should respect from where you got the idea. Here no one will give you accurate solve they will show you how to solve it. If you would share the whole code then I would also share it fully.

Comment: Your idea undoubtedly helped me a lot to reach the solution. I shared the solution so that people can solve the same problem easily. Don't take me negatively. I learned from your reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this

```js
<PhoneInput
  placeholder="Enter phone number"
  value={value}
  onChange={setValue}
  inputComponent={forwardRef((props, ref) => <input ref={ref} {...props} id=my_input_id_extra_passing_it" />)}
/>
```

Assuming you know how and where to import forwardRef